# É possível carregar links .css alternativos para o caso do link primário não estar funcionando?

Tags: html, css

Não é bem um problema, e sim uma dúvida que pode resolver vários dos meus problemas.

Digamos que eu carregue esse arquivo CSS pra meu site:

```
<link href='http://host-1.com/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

Mas se o **host-1.com** estiver fora do ar? Há alguma maneira de verificar isso e usar outro arquivo, exemplo:

```
<link href='http://host-2.com/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

Como se eu quisesse dizer assim pro meu código:

```
//Carregar esse arquivo css
<link href='http://host-1.com/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
//Mas no caso dele não funcionar, carregue esse:
<link href='http://host-2.com/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

Comment: Se for um "espelho" você pode incluir os dois, porem, isso vai obrigar o usuário a baixar os dois arquivos quando ambos estiverem funcionado.

Comment: Se o CSS for BEM enxuto, e a carga dele tão importante, você pode colocar ele inline na página (em um bloco <style>), garantindo que ele esteja presente sempre. Só tem que entender o custo disso: não aproveita cache em páginas diferentes, vai ser carregado toda vez, e dar um pouco mais de trabalho na manutenção (mas nem tanto quanto dizem). Nâo é o normal, mas se a situação requer, não é errado como o pessoal exagera por aí.

Comment: @Bacco para falar a verdade, se pega sites um pouquinho mais antigo para manutenção e isso é  bem utilizado se naum o mais..kkkk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, basta declará-los dentro da *tag* `head`.

Um exemplo seria:

```
<head>
    <link href='http://host-1.com/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='http://host-2.com/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>
```

O que acontecerá, é que os 2 serão carregados e 1 irá conflitar(mas vão carregar, o que vai conflitar é o CSS interno de ambos e dependendo vão se sobrepor) com o outro caso o conteúdo seja diferente. Caso não seja, o *browser* usará o último declarado.

Para fazer uma verificação se houve problema de carregamento de um arquivo específico antes de usá-lo, necessitará de uma linguagem de programação propriamente dita, o que está ausente em suas *tags*.

Comment: Poderia informar a causa do negativo, onde está o problema em minha resposta ?

Comment: Não fui eu que coloquei negativo '-'

Comment: Você não respondeu a pergunta. Foi requisitado um condicional para carregar a segunda opção, quando a primeira falha, no meu entendimento.

Comment: Mas me responde uma coisa, exemplo, você disse que eu posso declará-las na tag head, se eu declarar as duas, não vai ficar muito pesado para o usuário? Tipo ficar carregando dois arquivos? Ou dar algum erro, já que eu também quero fazer isso com arquivos .js?

Comment: Lembrando que quando não se tem uma resposta completa, porem tem uma dica valiosa, ou algo que pode ajudar, é possivel comentar a pergunta.

Comment: @mauhumor faz uma condicional para isso com css e html pra eu ver...

Comment: Ué, e por acaso eu respondi a pergunta?

Comment: @mauhumor não mas eu sim, se ler a resposta com atenção verá que está chamando a atenção de forma errada...

Comment: Se não tenho a resposta para o problema, simplesmente não crio uma resposta. E por isso que votei negativo.

Comment: Em primeiro lugar tua resposta foi editada. Segundo, ela não diz como fazer isso "Mas se o host-1.com estiver fora do ar? Há alguma maneira de verificar isso e usar outro arquivo, exemplo:". A resposta correta para esta pergunta é um simples. Não. E talvez uma dica de carregar os dos arquivos, como esta que você deu, só que para mim ficaria melhor em um comentário.

Comment: @LetíciaOliveira Se vai ficar pesado ou não depende do tamanho dos arquivos, para fazer de forma que só se carregue o arquivo necessário, precisa usar uma linguagem como php, o que está ausente na tag, mas minha resposta responde exatamente a pergunta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51376/discussion-between-magichat-and-mau-humor).

Comment: Sim, faço juz ao meu nick. Se estou equivocado, outros anularam meu voto negativo.

Comment: hehe fica assim naum, já tenho te observado acho vc um cara legal @mauhumor

Answer (score 8):

Em HTML puro não é possivel, mas se usar Javascript pode fazer algo como:

```js
function loadCssFallback(el)
{
    var url = el.getAttribute("data-fallback");
  
    console.log("Carregando fallback:", url);
  
    el.onerror = null;
    el.href = url;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="normal.css"
      onerror="loadCssFallback(this)"
      data-fallback="fallback.css"
>
```

Note que eu crie um atributo chamado `data-fallback`, ele deve conter o endereço do CSS alternativo.

Uma outra maneira, acaso tenha vários fallbacks, também usando JavaScript seria criando dinamicamente o elemento e testando com `onerror`. A função ficaria assim `loadCssFallback(<array com endereços css> [, <log>]);`, ficando assim:

- `loadCssFallback([ "//cdn.site.com/fallback.css", "css1.css" ]);` sem log no console
- `loadCssFallback([ "//cdn.site.com/fallback.css", "css1.css" ], true);` exibe o log no console

Exemplo completo:

```js
function loadCssFallback(urls, log)
{
    var link, current = 0;

    function done()
    {
        if (log && console) {
            console.log("Loaded", link.href);
        }

        link.onload = link.onerror = null;
    }

    function trigger()
    {
        if (log && console) {
            console.log("Iniciou...");
        }

        tryNext();
    }

    function tryNext()
    {
        current++;

        if (!urls[current]) {
             console.log("Nenhum CSS carregou");
             return;
        }

        loadCss(urls[current]);
    }

    function loadCss(url)
    {
        if (log && console) {
            console.log("Carregando CSS", current, urls[current]);
        }

        link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type = "text/css";

        link.onerror = tryNext;

        link.onload = done;

        link.href = url;

        document.head.appendChild(link);
    }

    //Verifica se a página já foi carregada
    if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(document.readyState)) {
        trigger();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', trigger);
    }
}

var meusCSSs = [
    "cssprincipal.css",
    "fallback1.css",
    "fallback2.css",
    "fallback3.css",
    "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/br/all.css?v=a482a814f698"
];

loadCssFallback(meusCSSs, true);
```

Comment: No caso do js estar desativado como faz ?

Comment: @MagicHat creio eu que praticamente todos sites feitos nos ultimos anos usem JS e se estiver com JS desligado ae vai causar outros problemas e esse será apenas mais um, ou seja não usar Javascript ligado hoje é quase o mesmo que haver um apagão geral, fazendo os principais meios de transporte pararem.

Comment: concordo, mas ao meu ver,  existe a possibilidade de oferecer 1 opção a mais, utilizando `html`.

Answer (score 2):

Puramente com html e css, eu desconheço algum método de fazer essa comparação. Mas se você utilizar uma linguagem servidor, como o php, poderá conseguir o que deseja.

Primeiro passo seria você delegar ao php o include do seu css da seguinte maneira:

```
<link href='css-handler.php' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

nesse arquivo `css-handler.php` você precisará de fazer o include do css, mas você terá ferramentas para fazer sua desejada condicional.
Essa condicional você pode fazer se utilizando do cURL:

```
<?php

function verifyIdCssExists($css) {
    // Verificar local 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $css);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Se achou, beleza, usa ele
    if($code == '200')
        die($data);
}

$cssOptions = [
    'http://host-1.com/style.css',
    'http://host-2.com/style.css',
    'http://host-3.com/style.css',
];

foreach($cssOptions as $cssLink)
    verifyIdCssExists($cssLink);
```

Esse código tá super meia boca, só pra ilustrar a ideia mesmo, mas funciona. Você pode aprimorar ele melhor caso seja de sua necessidade.

Comment: **PS:** gostei de ter feito com PHP, embora ache a solução do Guilherme melhor, melhorei o código para você.